# Magento 2: Remove custom customer attribute from register form

Tags: magento2, forms, register

I have a custom attribute test on the customer entity. By default it appears on the `register form`. I wish it would not.

EDIT The attribute has `is_user_defined` set to 1

Any tips?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don’t wish for a customer attribute to be shown in the registration form, make sure in the setting on this attribute, its value of

- Value Required = No
- Show On Storefront = No
- Or leave it to Yes, but remove the form you don't want it to show on in **Forms to Use In** selection.

Comment: not all form options (especially the admin html ones) are being displayed in the "Forms to Use In" - magento admin when you edit an attribute. any idea why?